# Qt - Write a multiple TCP server program

Tags: c++, qt

I'm going to write a program with more than one TCP servers listening on different ports.
But I can't find a sample or demo on this.
Should I create a thread for each server ?
Or could anyone give a link on some demo ?
Or give a overall description on the structure of the program ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find a sample for one server, you pretty much have a sample for multiple servers.

There is no need to make a thread for each server. You can create a `QTcpServer` object for each server and add handlers for their `newConnection` (see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpserver.html#newConnection) signals.

From there on it is the same like with one server.

Comment: [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtcpserver.html#newConnection)